# Understanding the Caesar Cipher code in Java

Tags: java

So I just need a little help understanding how this code works. I got this code from the internet but I can't clearly understand it though I completely understand how the Caesar Cipher works. The code version of it is a bit mysterious for me unfortunately. It would really be helpful if someone could walk me through what this code does.

```
public class CaesarCipherProgram{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "This is a secret";

    System.out.println( CaesarCipherProgram.encode( str, 3 ));
    System.out.println( CaesarCipherProgram.decode( CaesarCipherProgram.encode( str, 3), 3));
}

public static String decode(String enc, int offset) {
    return encode(enc, 26-offset);
}

public static String encode(String enc, int offset) {
    offset = offset % 26 + 26;
    StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
    for (char i : enc.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(i)) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(i)) {
                encoded.append((char) ('A' + (i - 'A' + offset) % 26 ));
            } else {
                encoded.append((char) ('a' + (i - 'a' + offset) % 26 ));
            }
        } else {
            encoded.append(i);
        }
    }
    return encoded.toString();
}
```

}

My Questions:

First, I dont understand how the modolus operator was used here to get our offset:

```
offset = offset % 26 + 26;
```

Second, why was the `StringBuilder` used instead of `String` for concatenation?

Lastly, I am a bit lost with this line of code. How does this work in the encrypting process? All I know is that it should return an upper case value when an upper case letter in the message is encrypted.

`((char) ('A' + (i - 'A' + offset) % 26 ))`

Any kind of help/explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
offset = offset % 26 + 26;
```

covers the possible case that the `offset` passed in was negative.  In Java, if the first argument to the `%` operator is negative, then the answer will be negative (or 0).  If it's negative, then `offset % 26` makes the result between `-25` and `0`, so that adding `26` will make it positive (it's just important that the result is non-negative here).  This way, adding the offset and doing `% 26` later will ensure that the resulting shifted character index is between `0` and `25` inclusive.

The `StringBuilder` class is used here as its primary purpose - to build a `String` without creating a temporary `String` object for every character added, wasting resources -- processing time and memory.

The `char` datatype can be converted (and thought of) as an `int` value that is the Unicode value of the character.  Capital letters `'A'` through `'Z'` are represented by the codes `65` through `90`, respectively.  Subtracting `'A'` from a `char` gives you an `int` that is between `0` and `25`.  The offset is added, and another `% 26` makes an encrypted `char` "wrap around" to the beginning again.  E.g. `'Z' + 3` => 25 + 3 => 28 => 2 => `'C'`.  You can add `'A'` back to get `65` through `90`.  That value is cast back to a `char` so that the proper character gets appended to the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: in your example, how did this happen: 28 => 2 => 'C' ?

Comment: There is another % 26 before it gets casted to a char.

Comment: Right, but how did we end up with 'C'? Is that the equivalent unicode value?

Comment: `28 % 26` is `2`.  `'A'` is promoted to `int` at `65`, and `65 + 2` is `67`.  `67` is casted back to `char`, which is `'C'`.

Answer (score 2):

- The modulo operator is used here to coerce the value to be between 26 and 51 (inclusive). `offset%26` is between 0 and 25, and adding 26 gets it to that range.
- StringBuilder is more efficient for strings than basic concatenation, since new objects do not need to be made for each concatenation. `append` is used to add to it and `toString` is used to get a String as a result.
- Characters are also numeric types. For example, `(int)('B'-'A')` is 1, A+3 is D, and so on. The uppercase characters are one consecutive block while lowercase characters are a separate consecutive block. The subtraction transforms a letter A-Z to a number 0-25. The addition and modulo results in another number, 0-25, and adding `'A'` results in a character, A-Z.